# Как отобразить список родительских категорий в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Битый час не могу понять, как мне отобразить список родительских категорий для хлебных крошек. Дочерние категории тоже нужны, кстати, но думаю там по аналогии.

Есть таблица категорий, в которой указаны ID родительских примерно в таком формате:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В контроллере:

```
public function category(Category $categoryName) {
$products = Product::getByCategoryName($categoryName->title);
return view('category.category', [
            'category' => $categoryName,
            'products' => $products,
           ]);
}
```

В модели Category следующее:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'name';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
    }
    public function getParentsAttribute() {
        $parents = collect([]);

        $parent = $this->parent;

        while(!is_null($parent)) {
            $parents->push($parent);
            $parent = $parent->parent;
        }

        return $parents;
    }
}
```

А в blade делаю так:

```
 @if(count($category->parents))
    <td>{{ $category->parents->implode('-') }} <strong>-></strong> {{ $category->name }}</td>
@else
    <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
@endif
```

Подскажите, что не так? При моем раскладе я на выходе получаю только текущую категорию.

Comment: а `$category->children()` чем не подходит?

Comment: Чет я запутался совсем))
Пробую так в контроллере:
$test = Category::children();
dd($test);
Получаю ошибку:
Error
Using $this when not in object context

Comment: я писал про `$category->children()`, т.е вы получаете родительскую категорию и из нее получаете дочерние.

Comment: а Вы пытаетесь на классе метод вызвать, который не является статическим.

Comment: в данном случае `$category`  это переменная, а не класс

Comment: я кстати запутался в вашем вопросе... я наячал писать про дочерние, а в заголовке про родительские говориться.

Comment: в таком случае вам нужно вызывать `$category->parent()` и чтобы получить все родительские нужно их вызывать в цикле пока `$category->parent() != null`